# Why does "02/15/2019" <= "02/11/2019" when fetching records from database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$delivery_date = '02/12/2019';
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "
SELECT o.*
     , o.OID AS order_id
     , o_t_n.order_tracking_id
     , o_t_n.details AS tracking_notification_details 
  FROM bl_orders o 
  JOIN bl_orders_trackings o_t 
    ON o_t.OID = o.OrderNo 
  JOIN bl_order_tracking_notifications o_t_n 
    ON o_t_n.order_tracking_id = o_t.id 
 WHERE o.ODeliveryDate <= ':delivery_date' 
   AND t_n.isReturnReminderNotificationSent = 0
" );
$stmt->execute( [
    'delivery_date' => $delivery_date
] );
```

In my code above, ODeliveryDate is "02/15/2019", and $delivery_date is "02/11/2019". Why is it that even though ODeliveryDate is after $delivery_date, this record is still being fetched?

Comment: Why not store dates as dates and then compare them with dates?

Comment: how are you keeping your date in DB? seems to be a total mishap

Comment: Does your code even work? Shouldn't it be `WHERE o.ODeliveryDate <= :delivery_date AND...`?

Comment: $delivery_date is '02/12/2019' - but if I'm wrong change it to '02/11/2019'

Comment: @Strawberry but you are missing the point... how would MYSQL know what to do when you are comparing string to string with `<=`, it just sorts by string and checks which one is first

Comment: If you're comparing strings then anything with a higher month will get sorted last, regardless of the year/day.

Comment: Don't quote your bind handles, just use `WHERE o.ODeliveryDate <= :delivery_date`

Comment: It is obvious... `'02/15/2019'` is less than `':delivery_date'` (0 comes before :). You're not prparing the statement properly. But your main problem is storing dates as string.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, you're right, I was comparing "02/15/2019" with "'02/12/2019'". After getting rid of the quotes around :delivery_date, it worked

Comment: These dates are just a bunch of ASCII characters as far as MySQL is concerned. Use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. `YYYY-MM-DD` sorts properly, and as a plus is the native form that MySQL expects. This is how dates in `DATE` and `DATETIME` fields should be defined.

Comment: @FlashThunder I'm not sure what you mean. The comparison date is never even getting into MySQL. OP is comparing the stored date to the literal string `:delivery_date`, *not* the date string passed from the attempted bind.

Comment: @AlexHowansky if a field is defined as a date, it doesn't matter if you put it into quotes or not, at least in version 5.x or less, but maybe I'm just a dinosaur

Comment: @FlashThunder It's not a MySQL issue, it's a PHP issue. If you quote your bind handles, the query will fail regardless of database engine or field data type.

Comment: @AlexHowansky oh you're right, sorry... tired after 40 hours of non-stop working with a project that had to be done for today, cheers :)

Comment: @Donny I don't have a MySQL server handy to test, but I would think that the call to execute() should at least generate a warning because you passed one parameter but had no binds. Did you get any warnings?

Comment: @FlashThunder It's Friday, have a beer, then a nap. :)